# Best method for dividing list into equal parts

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

I have a list more than 500 elements long.

I want to divide it into 5 lists, each of 100 elements.

```
mylist = [1......................700]
if len(mylist) > 100:
       newlist1 = mylist[0:100]
       someothelist = mylist[100:]
       if len(someotherlist) > 100:
           newlist2 = someotherlist[0:100]
           someotherlist2 = mylist[100:]
```

What's the best way to implement it using iteration?

Comment: This is the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python/312644

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python/312644